# Content Query Web Part and News Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I want to create a news site in which there will be two sort of pages:

1. Home Page: showing the main updated (last) article today.
2. News Page: showing a selected news.

Both pages should look like a simple news site (showing the main article) and both should have related last news on the side.

What I want to do, is a lot like what's mentioned in the site:
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160208012730/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ecm/archive/2010/05/14/what-s-new-with-the-content-query-web-part.aspx)

Problems:

1. This site only shows how to create the related news and not the main article.
2. I wanted to know how to do the same thing only without a news site (meaning a simple list with a Wiki field where the picture should be)
3. How can I (hoping its possible) take a Wiki field in CQWP and add smaller "width"?

Thank you in advance,
Mor Shemesh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a publishing site
2. On the default.aspx put s Conent Query web part, configure it to show 1 article, sorted by date in decending order
3. Create another welcome page and put a Content Query web part there also, configure it to show several item, according to the filter you need